# model serializer makes _writable_fields empty

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with django rest framework and I get some strange behavior with serializer.

I got some model with fields, and one of them is integer field with choices. When I'm trying to create serializer instance for my model I get an instance with empty _writable_field attribute, where my fields must be. I spend some time but I found problem place.

When I'm giving choices like this

```
[(1, '1'),(2,'lust')]
```

I'm getting this fail with fields, but when I giving choices like this

```
('1','1'),('2','lust')]
```

serializer works fine, but I'm getting a validation error because it is Integer field.

I can't debug this problem, debugger also not perfect and makes mistakes when i'm looking deep in code.

Comment: Looks like I found problem. My serializer inherit custom choice serializer which suppose that choice will be a string.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

`((1, u'1'),(2, u'lust'))`

Comment: First element in tuple makes difference. Second does not influence. But thanks for tip.